# How to find the normalized coefficients?

Tags: filters

I use the below matlab function to design the unquantised coefficient set:

> [b,a]=ellip (4,2,60,2*[0.2,0.3]);

and then i use the matlab finction "tf2sos" to convert the direct form coefficients to a set of a factorized second-order sections:

> [sos,g]=tf2sos(b,a);

My result is:

[image]

The normalized version of the difference equation is:

[image]

How i can find the b and the c1,c2,...

Is the actual result in this form:

[image]

or factorized means normalized and the result is in this form:

[image]

The gain plays any special role?

Comment: [Doesn't the manual tell you](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf2sos.html)?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're taking it directly from the manual.  I think that in the first `sos` array $b_{01} = bc_{1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you define your normalized difference equation, but in any case you can equate the $b_{ij}$ coefficents in the sos matrix with your $c$ coefficients, and the gain that tf2sos returns would then be your normalization constant $b$.

I think you already know, but just to be clear: every row of the sos matrix contains the coefficients for one second-order section, starting with the 3 numerator coefficients, and then the denominator coefficients (the first of which is always 1). You can incorporate the gain into the first section.

Comment: You mean that my normalized coefficients are:                first line: 0.005 ,0.0087635, 0.005, 0.005, 0.001252,0.0042305 etc for the rest of them?

Comment: No, the gain only applies to the b coefficients (of the first row), the a coefficients remain unchanged.

Comment: Yes, you are right.Stupid question... This applies only in the first row? In the second the coefficients remains unchanged?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would scale the whole filter by $g^2$ instead of by $g$.